# how to specify a binding value in a collectionview?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a CollectionView inside which has a custom View.

I want to specify the property of the customview dynamically so I add a Binding Value to the customView but obviously it need a Property in the Binding Data.

But I want to specify it in the cs file.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<local:MyView WidthRequest="{Binding Width}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

obviously I need add a Width property in the Items.But I do not want it.
Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Could you provide the full code of the xaml and your custom view?

Comment: please just add a ContentVIew in a CollectionView's DataTemplate and see if it displayed if you do not specify a height property

Comment: You can check my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different from **Button** and **Image** . **ContentView** will not have a default size if you don't set the child elements .

So if you want to set the size in runtime , use data binding is the best way . If you don't want to define the property in model and set it multi times , you can set the binding path of the ContentView . In this way you should make sure that each row has the same height .

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XXX"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="contentPage"  // set the name
             x:Class="XXX.MainPage">
```

```
<local:MyView HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentPage},Path=BindingContext.Height}" />
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public double Height {get; private set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<Grid>` with one column specifying it's width as `Auto` 
instead of binding dynamic `Width`:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <local:MyView Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: It is worked but if I use row to specify it's height with auto it is not worked.

Comment: can you post the screen how it look like?

Comment: it only has a 1 pixel height.

Answer (score 0):

I have a not so better solution.
I created a style which specify the `HeightReqeust` and `WidthRequest` of the customView.

and I specify the value in the cs file.

till now I have not found a better solution.